# Outlook express downloading email into inbox and outbox

Tags: outlook-express

I've got an issue with Outlook Express where when I press Send and Receive the messages download as per usual into my Inbox but an exact same copy of the Inbox messages downloads into the Outbox as well which then immediately sends those messages out (or back rather to the sender) whilst still in Send/Receive mode.

I've renamed the outbox.dbx but that didn't work and I'm stumped.

Any advice would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Have you got any [rules defined](http://www.austincc.edu/ITdocs/Outlook/oerules.html) for incoming mail?

Comment: Hi Thechie007, thanks for the heads up, this was the only thing that I didn't check, suppose starting with the simplest things first always helps, also I was thinking from an Office 365 perspective since that's what we're using, but after I switched off the out of office reply rule, it all worked smoothly.  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, it surely was an old 'out of office' reply that I had set up that was the culprit.  I was looking at this from the wrong angle, we use Office 365 and I never set up a rule there.  Anyways thanks a million again.